# static variables - another keyword i can use for instance variable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, static, rss

I am using a app that takes the RSS Feed of the apple live feed using XML and NSXMLParser. I am sorting it into categories so that everything which is related to Steve Jobs (I sort it using NSRange to strings) will display in that category. You select a category using a UIPickerView. I have a method which is called whenever a Finance category is found. This is in a class called RSSItem:

```
   if (revenue.location != NSNotFound || earnings.location != NSNotFound || quarter.location != NSNotFound) {
//  categoryKey = @"Finance";
if (currentString) {
    [arr addObject:currentString];
    NSLog(@"%i" , [arr count]);
}
 }
```

currentString is the string which is the title of the article/rss feed post. Now I had to make arr a static variable in the implementation otherwise it would always turn out as an empty array. Now it logs the array to a count of 8. Here is the declaration.

```
  @implementation RSSItem
  static NSMutableArray *arr;
```

So now I need to distribute that array to a TableViewController class called Finance but whenever I try it always turns out empty. So then I tried making a model for the TableViewController which is a subclass of RSSItem. I need to access that static variable in this new class. Can I create a static property or variable. If I can't do this can you provide me with an approach to distribute this array and NOT LET IT BECOME EMPTY. I am actually not sure why it becomes empty. If you know why, please tell me and please answer my above questions. Thank you!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045051/static-instance-variable.

Comment: @user1172792: Your title mentions "static" and "instance variable" - which is a contradiction. The one answer posted so far explains how to manage, and make available to other classes, an instance variable. Do you really wish a "static" - an array shared by all instances of your class - or "instance" - one array per instance of your class? The answer is different depending on the need...

Answer (score 1):

Declaring as a static is most like having a class variable. Assuming I understand your issue correctly you have an array created by one class that you want to pass into another class?

In your RSSItem class I would have a property

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Then of course you will need to synthesise it

```
@synthesize array = _array;
```

In you init method for you RSSItem class:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.array = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
```

This will give you an empty NSMutableArray to work with

Then instead of your line

```
[arr addObject:currentString];
```

use:

```
[self.array addObject:currentString];
```

in your table controller you presumable have access to you instance of your RSSItem object, so you will be able to access its array by doing:

```
NSArray *arrayInTableController = (NSArray *)myRSSItem.array
```

And finally you will need to make sure you override dealloc in your RSSItem class:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.array = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This should allow you to get hold of the array in your table controller. You can then do with it what you like.

Hope this was of some help to you. If you found it unclear or need any further help, please don't hesitate to let me know :)

Comment: I Receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
kill
error while killing target (killing anyway): warning: error on line 2184 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1708/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "void macosx_kill_inferior_safe()": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Where are you getting this error? When you try to create the array? when you pass it to the other controllers, or when the other controllers try and use it?